# Can Jira categorize issues from email?

Tags: jira, email, bug-reporting

We are trying to migrate our current in-house system to Jira, and I am investigating "if and how" Jira can replace our automated bug reporting. So first a few words on what we're currently doing:

1. Whenever one of our (many) production systems detect an unhandled exception, it sends an email to a mailbox. The subject line of the email contains some info about the originating system, and the body contains further details and/or a stack trace.

   - If needed, we can modify the format and contents of these emails.
2. Our bug reporting system monitors the mailbox and picks up any new emails. These are then analysed for content, and new bugs are created:

   - assigning each bug to its appropriate project,
   - populating fields with the class, method, line number, and possibly call stack and stack trace from the email.
   - However, re-occurrences of already-reported bugs are simply counted as such, rather than creating many duplicate bug reports.

I can [read online](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/creating-issues-and-comments-from-email-802592933.html) that "one can send email to Jira" and have Jira create issues from that. But...

- I cannot figure out whether it is possible to automate routing the issues to the appropriate projects (based on mail contents). Two suggestions are to create a dummy project for collection and then manually distribute them; and creating a new mailbox for each and every project -- neither is very scalable, and we really want this to happen automatically.
- I cannot figure out whether it is possible to extract metadata from the subject or body of emails -- or whether Jira just considers the whole email body (possibly without history and quotes) as one entity.

It seems to me that we cannot be the first company to have come up with this system, and there *must* be a configuration, feature, or plugin for Jira that does something not entirely unlike this...

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro you just need SIL plugins in jira so you can send email what ever events happen in your jira, you can get the whole detail of the email sent to the jira email you used. currently im building my own function for the sending emails, and incoming emails. If you know how to code it is easy to you to know SIL. if not then you can still learn this ill send you a reference that you can use in long run. here it is:
https://confluence.cprime.io/display/SIL

if you need some code advise feel free to ask me. thanks

Comment: One of us is misunderstanding, I think. Doesn't this send email *from* Jira? I need to classify email sent *to* Jira.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong you need a function to send and recieved email in jira for your further function you need in jira? for short you need to run all functionality automated using email functions?

if yes jira has plugin the "SIL"

You can route the issue if the project key is indicated in the email for basis,

For metadata i suggest you can put it in the attachment of the issue.

if this is not the answer for your question just tell me. thank you

Comment: Sorry, @Dee, no offence intended - it might very well be _me_ who's misunderstanding.

Comment: Im so sorry for that

Comment: No reason to be sorry. Be happy! 8-d:-)

Comment: Just FYI, Power Scripts can process incoming mail. It has programmable mail handler. It can also send emails (based on some templates). So @Dee was right to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the **E-mail This Issue** add-on.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.metainf.jira.plugin.emailissue/server/overview

It is able to parse incoming mails based on summary or body, then create new or locate existing Jira issues. And it's for a reasonable price (comparing to other similar add-on) and the vendor is responding and helpful.

Regards,
Radek